# Preventing multiple reinitialization of Metaeditor / player on Browsers

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'm building a online video chat like project where the I have two components.

One component contains: A bot avatar from unreal engine, and on the right on a small window, the user's camera feed is shown.

Whereas, the second component contains: A display where user can answer questions such as dropdown, radio buttons or checkboxes. and on the right, the bot avatar and just below aligned is the user feed.

These two components need to switch based on the users response. But the issue is, the player from "pixel-streaming" tries to reconnect every time the components switch.

I was wondering, is there a way, where i can initialize the player only once, and use that same reference on both the components, whenever they rerender, to prevent the reconnecting? and have a seamless uninterrupted feed from the avatar without reconnecting everytime the component switches?

Im currently using pixel-streaming v4.3.13

with Next js

Any help would be highly appreciated.

So far, I've tried these approaches.

1. Prop drilling the pixel-streaming player to individual components.
2. Using ref: created a ref on the parent component and passed it down to the player and initialized it, and checking if we have the ref, then use existing ref, else initialize it.
3. Using contexts, defined the player component and initial value, and tried to access it on Indvidual component.
4. Memoizing to stop re render, if props haven't changed.